# Dynamically adding MySQL fields in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I have managed to create a script which appends input textboxes with a click of a button with the help of javascript, but what i want is to create unlimited number of MYSQL field and persist the data to the database using html form.

Currently i have set javascript to populate only 10 input textboxes because i have only created 10 fields in MySQL table.

is there a way i can create MySQL fields on demand and not limit to 10 fields or is there another solution to this problem using laravel.

Here is The Html code

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/Reward_details', )) }}

{{ csrf_field() }}

<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-6">
  <b>Prize#1</b><br>

<div class="form-group">
  {{ Form::label('pledged_amount', 'Pledged Amount:') }}
  {{ Form::text('pledged_amount', null, ['class' => 'form-control', "required", 'placeholder' => 'Add Pledged Amount']) }}

</div>


<div class="form-group">
  {{ Form::label('reward', 'Reward Description:') }}
  {{ Form::textarea('reward_description', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => '5', "required"]) }}

</div>


<div class="input_fields_wrap"><br><br><br><br>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <a class=" btn btn-success col-lg-12 btn-margin-top add_field_button">Add Reward Per Pledge</a>
    </div>

</div>

  </div>
  </div>

<hr>

<div class="col-mid-12">
    <div class="form-group">

        {{ Form::submit('Submit Reward Details', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}

    </div>
</div>


{{ Form::close() }}
```

and here is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var n = 0;
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    var i=1;// counts the number on Prizes
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            n++;
            x++;
            i++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).prepend('<div class="col-md-12 nopadding form-group">' +
            '<p>Prize#'+ +i +'</p>'+

            '<label for="pledged_amount">Pledged Amount:</label>' +
            '<input class="form-control" type="text" name="pledged_amount'+ +n +'" required/><br>'+ 

            '<label for="pledged_amount">Reward Description:</label>'+
            '<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" type="text" name="reward_description'+ +n +'" required/></textarea><br>'+

            '<a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger remove_field">Remove</a>'+
            '</div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

The script just appends 10 input textboxes because i have created only ten Fields in mysql.

Comment: By fields you mean table columns right?

Comment: yes, MYSQL table columns

Comment: Then you should not do that. There is no point in making 'infinite' number of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should not create infinite number of columns**

Rather you should name your input fields as array

Let's say:
`pledge_amount[]`

And get this array in the backend as array. Loop thorough this and enter rows in your table rather than adding columns.

Comment: Thanks i had not thought of that.

Comment: This makes querying a nightmare and you can throw indexing out the window as well. There are cases where dynamic columns are acceptable.